# What are the correct steps to build a SaaS B2B company UX experience?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, design-process, ux-integration

I'm currently working for a SaaS B2B project in a specific niche, and this is my first experience of a kind.

On of my first toughts is to have a consistente user experience throughout the customer journey with the company:

1. The brand name and colors that remit to what the software does (and all of its collaterals - business cards, template presentations, folders, etc.)
2. The company web page with its call to actions specific for a certain
   point in the customer journey, sending specific messages during these points.
3. The software UI itself

At the end, a consistent UX depends on consistency on these points, and that is recognized if we look at Salesforce, Box, Workday or other top successfull SaaS B2B companies.

My doubts on this topic is related to the process of building this consistency in defined and sequential steps. I'm an UX developer, not a designer, and wish to know how to estabilish a formal and consitent process to build what I call "The company user experience" - the 3 steps above. Consider that I will be working with different people, some of then third party, to make this work. Consider also that I have several sprints on the product development cycle.

So, I would think of something like:

```
a) Define company goals and history
b) Build the Logo and Collaterals
c) Define the product stories (what is it for, problem solved, customer stories)
d) Define customer buying journey
e) Build the website
f) Define the product UI Libraries (Web and Mobile)
g) Develop product sprints (UI + Business Logic)
h) Go back to (c) and start over
```

Thinking that way, I'am having too many doubts on how to make it work. Examples:

- Should I really start with the Logo?
- Should I first do (a), (c) and (d) before going to development of Logo, website and UI Library?
- Can I develop the website in parallel of the UI Libraries, or should serially ?
- How to handle different people on different steps?
- Are there any important steps missing?

My final goal is an structured process to follow in order to be build these whole tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Well one is UX or CX in your case, and one is company strategy. You should ask for inputs from your Chefs, regarding; who exactly are you competitors, who are clients, what are your goals, what are your advantages over competetion, and based on that decide **what and how you want to communicate**.

Steps I can think of out of head;

1. Determine visual communication style - how formal or relaxed will your texts be, how sales oriented or neutral, and so on
2. Based on 1. - Choose fonts and colors, do some branding, create Stylesheet
3. Create logo, slogan
4. Create promotional designs; for Print and create Website design. If you wanna go detailed you could connect 3. and 4. and create **Design system**
5. Create design for your software (that must not be same as website / company design, you can brand your software differently if you want)
6. Establish UX testing framework (steps to repeat and test). Not all of design work needs to be iterative / changed, after testing you can just change some parts. Listen data from Google Analytics and Hotjar i.e., perform A/B testing

Points on your questions:

- Logo is part of wider communication strategy. You can start with small styleheet (logo, colors, fonts), go with branding document, or even build whole design system in begninig
- For me seems logical to first define process, yes
- Website and UI Libraries can parallely developed, if you have your visual guidlines from first points defined. Or also if you will have separate design for website and Software UI
- This is too general question. Is part of business logic, Modern "stack is" standup meetings, sprints, no deadlines, no hierarchy, transparent, lot of communication done with prototypes and visuals, quick turnarounds
- IMO, your steps are good. There is lot of substeps available which you need to determine based on your specific case inside company

Comment: Thanks @xul for the feedback... Very usefulll hints...